# Disallowing more then one user to work on a Queue Item

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to enforce that more then 1 user should not work on a QueueItem. How does setting QueueItem.WorkerId helps in this? What happened in the background when this attribute is set? How else we can enforce the above restriction in CRM 2011.

At the moment even if I set the WorkerId attribute by choosing WorkOn action other user can still opens the QueueItem and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is to challenge your requirement (for example: if the user working on the item leaves the company before the item is resolved - what should happen?) - but I'll assume your question is purely a technical one.

Here would be my suggestion (untested - you'll need to do some work with this to prove which route is correct). My initial assumption was that queue items are allocated to users or teams based on the `queueid` attribute, but as you point out, the `workerid` attribute is perhaps a more likely candidate.

### Assuming WorkerId is the driver field:

I'll assume that there is no default value in the `workerid` attribute. You will need to write a plugin that is registered against the `Pre-Operation` stage of the `Update` message of the `queueitem` entity. If the `workerid` attribute is *not* already set (get this from a Pre-Entity image) then allow the operation to proceed. If the `workerid` is *already* set then raise an exception to the user that informs them that the item cannot be reallocated. You may need to register your plugin against the `Create` message of the `queueitem` too.

### Assuming QueueId is the driver field:

Add a new attribute to the `queueitem` entity, called something like "Original queue". Then write a plugin that is registered against the `AddToQueue` message of the `queueitem` entity (I originally believed this is the message that is fired when a user clicks the "Work On" button - which I thought moved the item to the users queue, but I may be wrong). If your "Original Queue" attribute is *not* set, then set it to the old queue id (get this from a Pre-Entity image) and allow the reallocation to another queue to proceed. If the "Original Queue" item is *already* set then raise an exception to the user that informs them that the item cannot be reallocated. You may need to register your plugin against the `Create` message of the `queueitem` too (I'm not sure, without testing, at which point an incoming queue item is allocated to the queue).